# How can I read a CSV file from a link and get an average of a column of data using C#?

Tags: c#, html, csv, etl, average

i'm trying to download a csv file from an URL, read it and transform it's data into a visualization via HTML, so basically an ETL-process.
However I'm struggling with averaging the data and getting a result.

I tried checking for average with Console.WriteLine but it's NaN, so there is either a problem with averaging the data or with reading it.

Can anyone help me out and point out where the issue may lie?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ETL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://www.file-upload.net/download-15071709/data.csv.html";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string data = client.DownloadString(url);

      
            string fileName = "one.csv";
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, data);

           
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    
            double sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                if (values[0] == "Strom")
                {
                    sum += double.Parse(values[1]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            double average = sum / count;

            string html = $"<html><body><p>Average power consumption is: {average}</p></body></html>";
            File.WriteAllText("index.html", html);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help! :D

Comment: It doesn't seem optimal to write the data to a file only to read the same data from that file immediately afterwards. Just get the lines by splitting `data`.

Comment: Before calculating the average, you could check if `count == 0` and if it does then show a message that no data were found in the file.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is actually fine but the URL is not a download link for the CSV file. Therefore, you're parsing the web form. In other words: raw HTML code.

I tried your code with `https://filesamples.com/samples/document/csv/sample4.csv` and it returns the CSV correctly.

Comment: So when you run it you get the correct result instead of NaN? Because it does let me run the code but the html file it creates at the end to visualize it doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: @DannyD: `string data` does not contain what you think it does. [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Olivier is right: Your `lines` contain the HTML code. That looks like this: ```[0] = {string} "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""``` and so on. Not the CSV content.

Comment: @DannyD Is your question answered with what was provided? If yes, please feel free to accept the answer.